# Put a JPanel class into a JFrame of another class

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have to insert into a JFrame, a JPanel of another class.
I have a jMenuItem into the JFrame and i want that, when i click on the JMenuItem, the JPanel will appear.

```
 private void searchStudMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        searchStud s = new searchStud();
        s.setVisible(true);
        changePanel(s);
    }                                                  

    private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        getContentPane().doLayout();
        update(getGraphics());
    }
```

searchStud is the class that contain the JPanel.
When i execute the program and i click on the JMenuItem, nothing happens...
I tried searching online but what I find does not work.

Comment: can you please use `invalidate();validate();`, after the `update(getGraphics());`

Comment: done but nothing happens... 
I tried to print a string in the console to see if the JPanel was reached and is actually reached but it is not shown to video

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual component - a JFrame I suppose - was changed, it must be revalidated:

```
private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    getContentPane().add(panel);
    revalidate();
}
```

Just tested with this minimal code:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }


    private static class searchStud extends JPanel {
        searchStud() {
            add(new JLabel("SEARCH STUD"));
        }
    }


    private Test() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(this::initGUI);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        JButton button = new JButton("Search");
        button.addActionListener(this::searchStudMenuItemActionPerformed);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        add(button);
        setSize(300, 200);
        validate();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void searchStudMenuItemActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
        searchStud s = new searchStud();
        s.setVisible(true);
        changePanel(s);
    }                                                  

    private void changePanel(JPanel panel) {
        getContentPane().removeAll();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use revalidate(). validate() is the older AWT method. revalidate() is the newer method added for Swing.